# function checkForm() doesn't work with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

OK so this works on all and every browser ive tried it on, but when i try it  with internet explorer, its like i dont even have the CheckForm Action there. Any help at all would be awesome. Here is the Script.

```
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
    var d = document;
    if (d.images) {
        if (!d.MM_p) d.MM_p = new Array();

        var i, j = d.MM_p.length,
            a = MM_preloadImages.arguments;
        for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++)

        if (a[i].indexOf("#") != 0) {
            d.MM_p[j] = new Image;
            d.MM_p[j++].src = a[i];
        }
    }
}

function checkForm() {
    var errors = "";

    if (isEmpty("Name")) {
        errors += "- Name missing\n";
    }

    if (isEmpty("Email")) {
        errors += "- Email missing\n";
    }

    if (isEmpty("Phone")) {
        errors += "- Phone missing\n";
    }

    if (isEmpty("Dateneed")) {
        errors += "- Date Needed Missing\n";
    }

    if (isEmpty("ZipCode")) {
        errors += "- Zip code mising\n";
    }

    if (errors.length != 0) {
        errors += "\n";
    }

    var rad_val = document.form1.LanyardStyle.value;

    var quantity = parseInt(document.form1.Quantity2.value);
    if (isNaN(quantity)) {
        quantity = 0;
    }

    if (rad_val == 'Polyester' && quantity < 100) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for Polyester is 100";
    }

    else if (rad_val == 'AntiMicro' && quantity < 100) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for AntiMicro is 100";
    }

    else if (rad_val == 'Bamboo' && quantity < 100) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for Bamboo is 100";
    }

    else if (rad_val == 'PET' && quantity < 100) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for PET is 100";
    }

    else if (rad_val == 'Reflective' && quantity < 100) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for Reflective is 100";
    }

    else if (rad_val == 'Dyesub' && quantity < 200) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for Dyesub is 200";
    }

    else if (rad_val == 'Woven' && quantity < 500) {
        errors += "- Minimum order for Woven is 500";
    }

    if (errors.length > 0) {
        alert("Information missing or invalid:\n\n" + errors);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function getText(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).value.trim();
}

function isEmpty(id) {
    if (getText(id).length == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please place your code inside a code block, and format the code somewhat? It makes it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: Could you explain further what happens on IE? Are you getting an error? I'm assuming JS is enabled?

Comment: Brandon, you haven't provided the code showing how the `checkForm` function is connected to the HTML form `form1`.  That is most likely where IE is expecting something different than other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function checkForm() {
    var rad = document.form1.LanyardStyle.value,
        quantity = parseInt(document.form1.Quantity2.value, 10) || 0,
        errors = '',
        fields = ['Name', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Dateend', 'ZipCode'],        
        min = {'Polyester':100, 'AntiMicro':100, 'Bamboo':100, 'PET':100,
               'Reflective':100, 'Dyesub':200, 'Woven':500};

    for (var i = 0, l = fields.length; i < l; i++) {
        if ( isEmpty(fields[i]) ) {
            errors +=  '- ' + fields[i] + ' missing\n';  
        }   
    }

    if ( quantity < min[rad] ) {
        errors += '- Minimum order for ' + rad + ' is ' + min[rad];    
    }

    if ( errors ) {
        alert('Information missing or invalid:\n\n' + errors);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```